# Equal row-products and column-products in a given array

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, number-theory

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I'm stuck on this and can't figure out how to even proceed. Any hints anyone?

Is it possible in a 5 × 5 array of integers for all row products to be equal to 1 modulo
4 and for all column products to be equal to 3 modulo 4?

Comment: A quick hint: what can you say about the product of all the integers in the array?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> no

because

> the product of five numbers each congruent to 1 mod 4 must itself be congruent to 1 mod 4

and

> the product of five numbers each congruent to 3 mod 4 must be congruent to 3 mod 4,

so

> the product of all twenty-five numbers in the grid must be congruent to both 1 and 3 mod 4, contradiction.

(This is a step-by-step answer, so you can treat the spoilertags, after the first one which is a one-word yes/no answer, as successive hints towards the solution. See how few you need to look at before figuring it out!)